# sfml-graphics-2.dll is missing from sfml lib folder

Tags: c++, dll, sfml

I'm new to c++ and sfml, and I've been trying to install sfml 2.3 on my computer for making games with c++ in **code::blocks**. I downloaded sfml and watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt0CiMGzBo8) video on how to set it up. I followed everything to the letter. When I tried to run the sample code from the sfml tutorial I got this error: **This application has failed to start because sfml-graphics-2.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.** I searched for solutions to my problem and found someone suggesting to move all the .dll files from your library into the area where the program would run. I went to my library folder in my sfml-2.3 folder, and looked for anything with a .dll ending. I found **zero** files with this ending. All of the files in this folder end in .a, so I watched [another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbWavdiod1Q) video on how to install sfml with code::blocks this video showed the sfml library folder with a number of files that ended in .dll I searched my computer for all sfml-graphics-2.dll files and came up with zero files again. I then downloaded every different version of sfml and couldn't find any .dll  files in any of their lib folders. Am I missing something, or do I just not have the .dll files, and if I don't where can I get them? I'm running widows xp if that helps.

Comment: Wrong download? The one for *Windows* (and GCC) has DLLs. http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3/

Comment: @deviantfan, mate there are no DLLs in the Windows ming

Answer (score 0):

.a is a Linux file extension for static libraries (Unix 'ar' archive). If you are on a Windows platform, download the correct version on SFML website. Dynamic libraries (DLL) are usually located in SFML-2.3/bin folder. You need to move the ones with a '-d' suffix in your Debug folder and the ones without in your Release folder to be able to run your program properly.

Comment: I don't know how I could have gotten the wrong download. : / Thanks for the help.